# jQuery 1.6 append a new div after a div

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on a tag 'a href' I have a function that adds a div at the end of another div like this:

```
$('<div>bla</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#inputs');
```

But when the function is executed it appears

```
<div style> bla </ div>
```

I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

**Edit:**
I want to append a div after another div on the click event of an anchor `<a>` tag.

Comment: And what exactly was the expected output?

Comment: Your actual code would help too.

Comment: Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjnuN/

Comment: The empty `style` attribute is a result of the `fadeIn()` call, which will be manipulating CSS properties on that element only. You may not get the exact HTML you expected (`<div>bla</div>`), but I don't see why it's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/zXwSf/

Something like this

```
/* here your "a" id */
$('#lol').click(function ()
                 {
                    $("<div/>").html("bla").css("display", "none").appendTo("#results").fadeIn(); 
                 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('<div>bla</div>').hide().appendTo('#inputs').fadeIn('slow');
```